# How do I remove a UIBezierPath drawing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, uibezierpath

I'm creating an app where you eventually have to sign, and I was wondering how you would clear the signature if they messed up?

**EDIT:**

Line Class:

```
#import "LinearInterpView.h"

@implementation LinearInterpView
{
    UIBezierPath *path; // (3)
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // (1)
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; // (2)
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect // (5)
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) clearPath{

    path = nil;
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

@end
```

And then in my other class "SecondViewController", I have a button which is connected to the IBAction clearMethod:

```
-(IBAction)clearMethod:(id)sender{

     LinearInterpView *theInstance = [[LinearInterpView alloc] init];
    [theInstance clearPath];

}
```

It contains the Line Class and calls the clearPath Method.

The part that is not working is what is inside of the clearPath function:

```
-(void) clearPath{

        path = nil;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the `bezierPath` to `nil` which clears the old bezier path!  and call  `[self setNeedsDisplay]` on the view where you draw the signature!

Comment: You should provide code of what your are doing and highlight what is not working for you.

Comment: you should not create a new instance of LinearInterpView whenever you want to clear the path.You should declare a property of LinearInterpView , and instantiate it only once when you start drawing the signature, and use the same property to call the clearPath method.

Answer (score 6):

To reset the UIBezierPath you should use -removeAllPoints

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using `drawRect` to render the bezier path, and clearing the text before drawing the path into the context. So, if you clear the path (throw the old one away and create a new empty one) then you'll just draw a clear rect...